# Haskell. Functions in Num expressions

Tags: function, haskell

I start to learn Haskell. While studying a tutorial I have found the following example that enables the usage of functions in arithmetic expressions:

```
module FunNat where

    instance Num a => Num (t -> a) where
        (+) = fun2 (+)
        (*) = fun2 (*)
        (-) = fun2 (-)

        abs      = fun1 abs
        signum   = fun1 signum

        fromInteger = const . fromInteger

    fun1 :: (a -> b) -> ((t -> a) -> (t -> b))
    fun1 = (.)

    fun2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((t -> a) -> (t -> b) -> (t -> c))
    fun2 op a b = \t -> a t `op` b t
```

The example works. But I can not understand how the `(+)` function is transformed into the function of two arguments. As I can understand each `(+)` is substituted with `fun2 (+)`. And fun2 is equivalent to the function of one argument `\t -> a t 'op' b t`, but we should have a function of two arguments (something like `(\t1 t2 -> (\x -> x ) t1 + (\x -> x) t2)` ). I think that here some basic concepts of Haskell typing should be applied but I do not know what they are.

**EDIT 1**

I understand that `fun2` is a function of three arguments. I can't understand internal expression transformation. I'm reasoning in the following way: `(+) 3 4` = `(+) (\x->3) (\x->4)` = `fun2 (+) (\x->3) (\x->4)` = `\t -> (\x->3) t + (\x->4) t`
What is this t? Or where am I wrong in my reasoning? May be it is necessary to think another way?

**EDIT 2**

I think that I have reached some understanding of the issue (thanks you all!). So:

1. When we write `(+) 3 4` - in this case a simple operation from `Num` is used, no special features from `FunNat`. To use `(+)` from `FunNat` it is necessary to write `fun2 (+) 3 4` or `fun2 (+) (\x -> 3) (\x -> 4)`. But these expressions expect any third parameter to be evaluated;
2. To demonstrate specific features from `FunNat` we may use the following example `((*)-(+))` (taken from tutorial) or in other form - `(-) (*) (+)`. Both expressions take two arguments. In this case we have: `((*)-(+))` = `fun2 (-) (*) (+)` = `\t -> (*) t - (+) t` = `\t -> (\t1 t2 -> t1 * t2) t - (\t1 t2 -> t1 + t2) t` = `(\t t2 -> t * t2) - (\t t2 -> t + t2)` = `\t t2 -> (t * t2) - (t + t2)`. The final expression expects just `Num`. I hope that all these are correct
3. As it was explained in tutorial, but I can't understand what for, the possibility to use `(*)` and `(+)` as parameters for `fun2` that expects `(t->a)` is based on the following (taken from tutorial): `t1 -> t2 -> a` = `t1->a'` where `a' = t2 -> a`. Here curring is used.

So all necessary facts were on the surface but I do not take into consideration the non-trivial mechanism of type inference.

Comment: `fun2 (+)` is equivalent to `\a b t -> a t + b t` by definition. It is really a function of 3 arguments - its type is `Num a => {-1-}(t -> a) -> {-2-}(t -> a) -> {-3-}t -> a`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I try to clarify the problem.

Comment: @ your edit.. `t` is the variable bound by the lambda. `(\x -> 3) t` is just `3` so `\t -> 3 + 4` is the final expression.

Comment: But in order to calculate `\t -> 3 + 4` we need to pass any t. I mean if we input `let f = \t -> 3 + 4` then to get result we need e.g. to enter f 42. I mean if it is correct that we end up with `\t -> (\x->3) t + (\x->4) t` expression we need some extra any t to evaluate it, i.e. `(+) 3 4 42`. Or not?

Comment: `(+) 3 4 = (+) (\x->3) (\x->4)` -- this is pretty much wrong. `3` has type `Integer`, but `\x -> 3` has type `a -> Integer`. Those two are not equal. As for the rest:

Comment: `fun2 (+) (\x->3) (\x->4) = \t -> (\x->3) t + (\x->4) t = \t -> const 3 t + const 4 t = \_ -> const 3 undefined + const 4 undefined = const (3+4)`

Sorry, accidentally submitted and didn't make an edit in time.

Comment: I agree that expressions `(+) 3 4 ` and `(+) (\x->3) (\x->4)` are not equivalent. But I think that we can make them so by passing one extra argument.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `(+)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a`. Since you're creating an instance of `Num` for the type `Num a => t -> a`, consider the explicit signature

`(+) :: Num a => (t -> a) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> a)` (1)

or equivalently (by currying)

`(+) :: Num a => (t -> a) -> (t -> a) -> t -> a` (2)

What this says is: "If you give me 2 strategies for producing a `Num a => a` from a `t`, I can create a new strategy for producing a `Num a => a` from a `t` by using the `Num.(+)` instance of the `a`'s"

I think the part that has you confused is that this specific `(+)` can be viewed as a function of 2 arguments which returns a function (1), or a function of 3 arguments which returns a value (2). Since functions in Haskell are curried, these are really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In type signatures parentheses associate to the right, so:

```
f :: a -> (b -> c -> d)
```

is the same as:

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

So the parens indicated below are redundant:

```
fun2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((t -> a) -> (t -> b) -> (t -> c))
                         ^                                ^
```

and removing them leaves:

```
fun2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> b) -> (t -> c)
          arg1             arg2        arg3
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I try to clarify the problem.